# Excel: Cell contents as formula requirements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple formula =sum(sum(d5*u300)/g4)
Is it possible to have the formula look up cell A1 for the d, a2 for the 5, a3 for the u, A4 for the 300, A5 for the the g and a6 for the 4. In other word each formula cell reference is made up of the contents of two other cells.This would be used in a selection process to produce a table for a graph. NON Excel Users could then use a drop down list in A1 to select column d etc.  With thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate your questions a bit..I feel indirect function is what you are after but your formula doesn't make any sense as you are adding only one cell (which is not required) using SUM function. The above formula will yield same result as (D5*U300)/G4

Comment: You're asking for the functionality of `indirect`, but usually if you're using `indirect` you're doing it wrong :-) (Mostly because it's a nightmare to edit and maintain.) Rather than specifying an address, a straightforward but naive improvement would be to specify a relative location using `offset` (eg from the referenced cell, move 1 down and 3 over).  I suspect, though, that what you really want is `sumifs`, summing data from a table according to given conditions.  What're you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
=SUM(SUM(INDIRECT(A1&A2)*INDIRECT(A3&A4))/INDIRECT(A5&A6))
```

? Let's say A1 contains `D` and A2 contains `5`. Then `INDIRECT(A1&A2)` will return the value of the cell D5.
However, I don't understand why you use `SUM` with just one argument.